# Software to search inside an EPUB file?

Tags: windows-7, text-search, epub

Is there Windows 7 software to help me search inside an EPUB file?

Comment: Try Calibre  http://calibre-ebook.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Calibre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibre_(software)):

- Microsoft Windows, Apple Mac OS X, Linux
- free, open source (GPL)
- can view and search inside an EPUB file:

[image]

(Sumatra PDF can view but cannot search inside an EPUB file:

[image]

)

Answer (score 1):

Sumatra PDF **can** search inside EPUB files with a minimun configuration:
Go to Settings -> Advanced Settings and it opens a "SumatraPDF-settings.txt" file. In that file, just change from the original (emphasis mine):

EbookUI [
...
UseFixedPageUI = **false**
]

to

EbookUI [
...
UseFixedPageUI = **true**
]

and save it.

Next time you open an epub file, you will have a toolbar with the Find option as shown:

[image]